# Selecting concurrent phone calls from DB

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a database with phone call records and each month, I'd bill clients based on it.

A record contains:

```
 ID - Owner - Caller_ID  - Calling_To - connect_time - disconnect_time - category
```

A client may own multiple numbers. If at any point 2 records had their connect_time overlapped, it's a concurrent call. E.g:

```
X1 - Alex - 0099989898 -  random number - 01:00:00 - 02:00:00 - international
X2 - Alex - 0055989898 -  random number - 01:30:00 - 01:50:00 - local
X3 - Alex - 0066666666 -  random number - 01:45:00 - 02:00:00 - local
```

X1 and X2 are concurrent calls.

My current query that I use to get the past month's records is as follows:

```
CallDataRecord::where('owner', 'Alex')
                ->whereBetween('connect_time', array($beginDate, $endDate))
                ->orderBy('connect_time', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

It's quite simple but I haven't had any success on where to begin to be able to query for concurrent calls.

I have made a PHP script using arrays and bunch of `if else` statements plus a function e.g. `isDateBetween` that I'd run all fetched records from the database in a `foreach` loop that would check if a number/record is *encapsulated?* by another number/record, thus getting the concurrent call. It is extremely slow.

I'd appreciate some guidance. Thank you.

Comment: how can I know which is multiple number of same client?

Comment: @sumit Sorry. I edited the table. They have an 'owner' field for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looping over the returned result in PHP will be very slow as the data will not be indexed, unlike a database system.

Below should return the data that you are looking for :

```
CallDataRecord::where('owner', 'Alex')
    ->whereBetween('connect_time', array($beginDate, $endDate))
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q->where('connect_time', '>=', 'connect_time')
        $q->where('connect_time', '<=', 'disconnect_time')
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($q) {
        $q->where('disconnect_time', '>=', 'connect_time')
        $q->where('disconnect_time', '<=', 'disconnect_time')
    })
    ->orderBy('connect_time', 'desc')
    ->get();
```